# Using sub-queries and filter in WHERE clause while joining tables

Tags: sql-server, join

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.Ticker),t2.SecurityID,t2.ClosePrice,t2.QuoteDateTime FROM [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityMasterDetails] as t1 
                INNER JOIN [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityPrices] as t2 
                ON t2.SecurityID =t1.SecurityID 
                WHERE t2.QuoteDateTime IN (SELECT max(QuoteDateTime) FROM [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityPrices]) AND t1.SecurityTypeName = 'REIT'
```

I get an output with no data. The subquery doesn't run along with the other filter in the WHERE clause. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can somebody please help!

Comment: So... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you have Valid data in you all the tables that can return the results after join and where clause??

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the lastest row from `SecurityPrices` for each `Ticker`, one option is to use `cross apply()`:

```
select --distinct /* distinct not needed if `Ticker` is unique on `smd`
   smd.Ticker
 , sp.SecurityID
 , sp.ClosePrice
 , sp.QuoteDateTime
from [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityMasterDetails] as smd
  cross apply (
    select top 1 
        i.SecurityID
      , i.ClosePrice
      , i.QuoteDateTime
    from [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityPrices] i
    where i.SecurityID = smd.SecurityID
    order by i.QuoteDateTime desc
    ) as sp
where SecurityTypeName = 'REIT' /* which table does this column belong to? */
```

Comment: My apologies, the SecurityTypeName is taken from table t1 - [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityMasterDetails]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting results because the `max(QuoteDateTime)` record doesn't have `SecurityTypeName = 'REIT'`. I think you want the `max(QuoteDateTime)` for this `SecurityTypeName`, so this can be done with an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (t1.Ticker),
    t2.SecurityID,
    t2.ClosePrice,
    t2.QuoteDateTime 
FROM [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityMasterDetails] as t1 
    INNER JOIN [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityPrices] as t2 
    ON t2.SecurityID =t1.SecurityID 
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT max(QuoteDateTime) DT FROM [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityPrices]) P on P.DT =  t2.QuoteDateTime
WHERE SecurityTypeName = 'REIT'
```

**EDIT**

Your data doesn't have what you think it does, I suspect. Here is how you can check...

```
--Find the SecurityID that matches the max date
SELECT 
    SecurityID , 
    max(QuoteDateTime) DT 
FROM [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityPrices]
GROUP BY SecurityID

--I'm betting this ID isn't in your SecurityMasterDetails where the Type is REIT
SELECT DISTINCT
    SecurityID
FROM SecurityMasterDetails
WHERE SecurityTypeName = 'REIT'
```

Since the SecurityID returned in the first query isn't in the second query result set, you are going to get NULL results.

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't specify it properly before, the QuoteDateTime and the SecurityTypeName aren't from the same table

Comment: I can't figure out why but again I am not getting any data in my output.

Comment: Same reason as before @SmithaShivakumar. The max(QuoteDateTime) record has a SecurityID  that isn't a REIT SecurityID .

Comment: Aagh! What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: check the edit i just made. Your query is operating correctly as all of these have. You can't make the dataset return something that isn't there or that doesn't meet the conditions @SmithaShivakumar

Comment: Thank you! @scsimon

Comment: Apologies on my late reply! But yes that helped me out.. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your query would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
                      t1.Ticker,
                      t2.SecurityID,
                      t2.ClosePrice,
                      t2.QuoteDateTime 
FROM [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityMasterDetails] as t1 
     INNER JOIN [Hub].[SecurityMaster].[SecurityPrices] as t2 ON t2.SecurityID =t1.SecurityID 
WHERE SecurityTypeName = 'REIT'
ORDER BY t2.QuoteDateTime DESC
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the dates in the database don't get ordered according to the most recent date.